# How to print error code from URL response in swift

Tags: ios, swift, parsing

I want to get error code that is 1009, I tried below code but getting value as zero

```
let err = error as NSError
        switch URLError.Code(rawValue: err.code) {
        case .notConnectedToInternet:
            showAlertForNoInternetConnection()
        default: break
        }
```

but  err.code value is zero, how can I parse to get 1009
Response :

> Error Domain=kmh.hjui.www Code=0 "Network connection error, please check the network" UserInfo={statusCode=0, NSLocalizedDescription=Network connection error, please check the network, NSUnderlyingError=0x302c8c600 {Error Domain=NSURLErrorDomain Code=-1009 "The Internet connection appears to be offline." UserInfo={_kCFStreamErrorCodeKey=50, NSUnderlyingError=0x302c84ea0 {Error Domain=kCFErrorDomainCFNetwork Code=-1009 "(null)" UserInfo={_kCFStreamErrorDomainKey=1, _kCFStreamErrorCodeKey=50, _NSURLErrorNWResolutionReportKey=Resolved 0 endpoints in 0ms using unknown from cache, _NSURLErrorNWPathKey=unsatisfied (No network route), fallback: {generation: 0}}}, _NSURLErrorFailingURLSessionTaskErrorKey=LocalDataTask`

Comment: You need to provide more information, adding a simple example to a playground that uses `URLSession.shared.data(from: url)` will give me the error with the code set if I run my playground with wi-fi turned off.  I used `catch let error as NSError { print(error.code, error.domain) }`

Comment: Try to "format" your error (see https://pastebin.com/eC6kMGdQ), and you should see that's be in your case `err.underlyingErrors.first.underlyingErrors.code` that you want (with some casts added), or with `err.userInfo[NSUnderlyingErrorKey].userInfo[NSUnderlyingErrorKey]`, I'd need to real value

Comment: check this answer: https://stackoverflow.com/a/53402874/14745547